# Difficult code to large sheet of stock returns

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Picture of excel sheet]

This is an example of a thinly traded stock, meaning that on some of the days, no trades occur and thus, the price (return) of the stock does not change (even though the stock might change in value in real life). Thus, we have to split the return between the days into the cells marked with red. Example: See stock A. From range(B3:B6) the return of the stock is equal to 20%, however, we want to split this return equally onto four days. See picture above.

In each column I want every red marked cell (equal to 0%) to be filled with the average of the next number different from zero in the column (The average of each day with no trading).

To make it even more tricky, I want to change the cell value of the number you find the average of, to be equal to the average number as well.

The picture is only an example - we have over 5000 stocks in our other sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this

```
Sub main()
    Dim col As Range, zerosRng As Range, area As Range

    With Worksheets("Stocks") '<--| change "Stocks" to your actual worksheet name
        For Each col In Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("C1", .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).EntireColumn).Columns
            With col
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="0%"
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
                    Set zerosRng = .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                    For Each area In zerosRng.Areas
                        area.Resize(area.Rows.count + 1).Value = area.Cells(area.Rows.count + 1, 1).Value / (area.Rows.count + 1)
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it :)